# add a child to an xml file using vb 6.0

Tags: xml, vb6, parent-child

This source code generates an XML with each new node attached to the root I want the nodes to be nested.

Rem-add info for a child node Ver 1A 6/24/15-next sample code 5/29/15

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim dom, node, attr

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set dom = CreateDOM


Set node = Nothing

' Create a comment for the document.
Set node = dom.createComment("sample xml file NEED A CHILD AND SUB CHILD.")
dom.appendChild node
Set node = Nothing

' Create the root element.
Dim root
Set root = dom.createElement("ReturnState")

' Create a "created" attribute for the root element and
' assign the "using dom" character data as the attribute value.
Set attr = dom.createAttribute("stateSchemaVersion")
attr.Value = "FSETV5.0"
root.setAttributeNode attr
Set attr = Nothing

' Add the root element to the DOM instance.
dom.appendChild root
' Insert a newline + tab.
root.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine)
' Create and add more nodes to the root element just created.
' Create a text element.
Set node = dom.createElement("SubmissionID")
node.Text = "1026132015623SUBID"
' Add text node to the root element.
root.appendChild node
Set node = Nothing
  ' Add a newline plus tab.
root.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbTab)

' Create an element 
Set node = dom.createElement("ReturnHeaderState")


Set node1 = dom.createElement("Jurisdiction")
node1.Text = "NYS"
' Add text node to the root element.
node.appendChild node1
Set node1 = Nothing

Set node1 = dom.createElement("TimeStamp")
node1.Text = "2013-24-06"
' Add text node to the root element.
node.appendChild node1
Set node1 = Nothing
```

Rem------------next varable
    ' Create an element 
    Set node2 = dom.createElement("PaidPreparerInformation")
    'node.appendChild node2: '6/23/15

```
Set node1 = dom.createElement("DateSigned")
node1.Text = "June 23 2015"
' Add text node to the root element.
node2.appendChild node1
Set node1 = Nothing

Set node1 = dom.createElement("TimeStamp")
node1.Text = "2013-24-06:12:36.23"
' Add text node to the root element.
node2.appendChild node1
```

dom.documentElement.appendChild node2

```
Set node2 = Nothing


Rem---replaced after sec node
dom.documentElement.appendChild node
''Set node = Nothing


Rem-removed because of line above
```

''   dom.documentElement.appendChild node1
    Set node = Nothing
      ' Add a newline plus tab.
    root.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)

Rem------------end next vara

```
' Create an element to hold three empty subelements.
Set node = dom.createElement("node3")

' Create a document fragment to be added to node3.
Set frag = dom.createDocumentFragment
    ' Add a newline + tab + tab.
frag.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab + vbTab)
frag.appendChild dom.createElement("subNode1")
   ' Add a newline + tab + tab.
frag.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab + vbTab)
frag.appendChild dom.createElement("subNode2")
   ' Add a newline + tab + tab.
frag.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab + vbTab)
frag.appendChild dom.createElement("subNode3")
   ' Add a newline + tab.
frag.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)
node.appendChild frag
Set frag = Nothing

root.appendChild node
   ' Add a newline.
root.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine)
Set node = Nothing

' Save the XML document to a file.
dom.save App.Path + "\TestForChild.xml"
Set root = Nothing
Set dom = Nothing
Exit Sub
```

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

rem----this is what my source code generates

`enter code here`- enter code here</code>  --> 
             - 
              1026132015623SUBID 
            - 
              June 23 2015 
             2013-24-06:12:36.23 
             
           - 
             NYS 
             2013-24-06 
             
           -

```
       REM---------this is what I want

       rem   I want the ReturnHeaderState to have children with additonal     nodes
       rem   like PaidPreparerInformation, Which has addtional nodes like date, name,
       rem   address not off the root.  I want them inside the ReturnHeaderState node.





       - <!-- sample xml file NEED A CHILD AND SUB CHILD.
        --> 
       - <ReturnState stateSchemaVersion="FSETV5.0">

         <SubmissionID>1026132015623SUBID</SubmissionID> 

       - <ReturnHeaderState>
         <Jurisdiction>NYS</Jurisdiction> 
         <TimeStamp>2013-24-06</TimeStamp> 

      - <PaidPreparerInformation>
        <DateSigned>June 23 2015</DateSigned> 
        <TimeStamp>2013-24-06:12:36.23</TimeStamp> 
        </PaidPreparerInformation>


      - <node3>
        <subNode1 /> 
        <subNode2 /> 
        <subNode3 /> 
        </node3>

        </ReturnHeaderState>

        </ReturnState>









       <ReturnHeaderState>
       <Jurisdication>NYS</Jurisdication>
       <TimeStamp>2015-06</TimeStamp>
       <PaidPreInfo>
```

Comment: Look at using the `appendChild` method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766535(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Code in the reference is not VB 6.0,  I have added children to the root that is not the problem.  They are not nesting correctly.

Comment: You're correct, the code is not VB6. It does demonstrate using the appendChild to add the child nodes to the node you want them "nested" under, not the root node.